# Oracle usage of a new sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this kind of question, if not, please accept my apologies.

I have just created a new sequence in my user schema which I can use:
--> `Select Seq_Testing.Nextval Into Variable From Dual;`

So far, no problem. But when I add in the user schema name Oracle gives me an error.
--> `Select User.Seq_Testing.Nextval Into Variable From Dual;`

Oracle gives me the error message

> PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor reference is out of scope.

Also, after adding grants and a public synonym I get the same error message.

```
Grant Select On User.Seq_Testing To User;
Create Public Synonym Seq_Testing For User.Seq_Testing;
```

For the record, this is an Oracle 11g database.

Any ideas are welcome.

Warm Regards

Comment: `USER` is a function, you can't use it as a prefix like that. You can use the actual schema name though. But why do you want to prefix it if you're using it within your schema anyway?

Comment: I have changed User and Variable for this post.

Comment: I want to use it because it is coming from old code, which I am not allowed to change.

Comment: Does that mean you aren't literally using `User` as you've shown in the question? What are you using then? If you're getting that error then it's a related scoping issue - perhaps you have a user name which is [a keyword or a reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words-and-Keywords.html#GUID-6A07BB21-AD82-4B47-80FA-9B1141CC23C2), and that is confusing the parser?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't really adding the user/schema name. [`USER` is a function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions227.htm):

> `USER` returns the name of the session user (the user who logged on) with the data type `VARCHAR2`.

So you can call it as a function:

```
select user from dual;

USER                          
------------------------------
MY_SCHEMA
```

But you can't use a function to supply [the schema qualifier](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements009.htm) in a statement. As you've seen, if you do

```
Select User.Seq_Testing.Nextval Into Variable From Dual;
```

then you get

> PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'USER' reference is out of scope
>   PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

You could specify the current user's schema using dynamic SQL:

```
execute immediate 'Select ' || User || '.Seq_Testing.Nextval From Dual' Into Variable ;
```

and it would then look for a sequence of that name in the executing user's schema at run-time; and will error if that doesn't exist. If you always want to use the same sequence owned by the same person, whoever executes this - which would be more normal - then you have to hard-code the schema name:

```
Select my_schema.Seq_Testing.Nextval Into Variable From Dual;
```

or more simply:

```
Variable := my_schema.Seq_Testing.Nextval;
```

or just:

```
Variable := Seq_Testing.Nextval;
```

As you have already seen you don't need to prefix an object in your own schema with the schema name, and there doesn't seem to be much benefit in doing so. If this is in a stored procedure or trigger then it will look for the sequence in the procedure/trigger-owner's schema anyway too, not in the calling user's schema. And if you really do want to have a separate sequence for each caller then it would have to be done dynamically, or they would have to have their own procedures too. That would be... unusual though.

Your privilege and public synonym statements have the same issue, thought hey get different errors. You only want (at most!) one public synonym and you can specify the actual schema name, or omit it if it's the current schema.

For the privileges you seem to be attempting to grant things on your own objects to yourself, which doesn't make sense either - you would normally `Grant Select On Seq_Testing To some_other_user`, assuming you want them to be able to increment that directly, not just through a stored procedure/trigger, which they don't need additional privileges for (other than execute on the procedure).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know it does not make sense to setup the grant for 'myself', but I was trying to figure out if I could get it to work. In the mean time I figured out it is working for another user. It must be something for that specific user.